# IBM Filenet: how to check access rights to delete

Tags: access-rights, filenet-content-engine

How to check programmatically if the currently connected user have access rights to delete the folder or a document in content engine object store? 
Can I do this with folder.getAccessAllowed() method and AccessLevel.* constants? 
(CE 5.0)

Answer (score 2):

`AccessLevel` is meant to represent a set of individual access rights. To check for specific right you should use something like this:

```
(object.getAccessAllowed() & AccessRight.DELETE_AS_INT) == AccessRight.DELETE_AS_INT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
int accessAllowed = document.getAccessAllowed();
if (checkRight(accessAllowed, AccessRight.DELETE))
{
    log.trace("Access level "
        + AccessRight.DELETE.toString() + " is present");
}

private boolean checkRight(int rights, AccessRight ar)
{
    return (rights & ar.getValue()) != 0;
}
```